# SQL Server query correction in nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
SELECT campus,semester, AVG(CountOfStudents)
FROM
(
  SELECT semester,year,campus, count(*) as CountOfStudents
  FROM regestration
  GROUP BY  semester, year, campus,student_id
) t
GROUP BY   campus,semester
```

I need to do is to find the average number of people per semester of each campus

My table structure is:

Table name - **registration**

```
student_id
campus
year
batch
semester
```

`campus`, `year`, `semester` and `batch` these can help identify unique records, where as `student_id` may repeat itself the query above gives wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- remove `student_ID` from the `GROUP BY` clause and
- add `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()`

query,

```
SELECT campus, semester, AVG(CountOfStudents)
FROM
(
  SELECT semester, year, campus, count(DISTINCT student_id) as CountOfStudents
  FROM   registration
  GROUP BY  semester, year, campus
) t
GROUP BY   campus, semester
```

Comment: You too =) have a nice day.